# graph of this is rectangular hyperbola?

Tags: geometry

taking $v$ as $x$ axis and $u$ as $y$ axis I would like to know whether ${1\over v}+{1\over u}={1\over f}$ has graph of the form $xy=c^2$?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite.

The shape is indeed a hyperbola with horizontal and vertical asymptotes, as does $xy=c^2$, but the center is moved. The center of $xy=c^2$ is at the origin, while your function has the center at the point $(f,f)$. The vertices of your graph are at the origin and $(2f,2f)$.

We can show this by rewriting your equation as

$$(x-f)(y-f)=f^2$$

And, as @Blue points out in a comment, there is a "hole" at the origin: the origin is on the hyperbola but not in the graph of your original equation.

This can also be shown by the standard conic-section technique of a change of variables causing a rotation of the axes of $x+y=xy/f$ by $45^\circ$. Here is a graph where $f=1$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but note that u=v=0 at the origin and that there is a displacement of x- y- axes at origin (f,f).

In fact KF Gauss had got rid of this reciprocal stuff to neatly introduce the displaced axes $ x\cdot y $ form useful in Optics:

$$ \frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v}=\frac{1}{f} $$
$$ u\, v  = ( u+v) f $$
$$ ( u-f) (v-f) = f^2 $$
$$ u_1 v_1 = f^2$$